# Server-side JavaScript (Rhino engine) - performance of importClass

Tags: javascript, performance, rhino

Is it true that importClass is inefficient and might be a performance bottleneck when there is a lot of traffic?

So, can the following be a performance bottleneck?

```
importClass(Packages.com.xxx.wrapper.ErrorWrapper);
var wrapper = new ErrorWrapper();
```

And is the following a solution to that (supposed) bottleneck?

```
var wrapper = new com.xxx.wrapper.ErrorWrapper();
```

Comment: are you sure that this is [tag:javascript]?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. http://www.ebooksbucket.com/javascript-the-definitive-guide-b18p308

Comment: @R.Ummels: Ah, indeed it is, but it's pretty much Rhino-specific.